# Nested Foreach Loops - Does it matter if I start with bigger or smaller array size?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Probably a stupid question here, but thought I should ask the experts.  I have a foreach loop with approximately 41 thousands values in an array, and I have another foreach loop with about 40 values in another array.  My question is, it doesn't really matter to me which `foreach` loop I start with, but I need to loop though both of these arrays recursively and wondering if there is a difference in PHP memory, or consumption if I start with the bigger loop vs starting with the smaller loop, and also, if the items in the array have anything to do with the memory consumption as well, for example, if there are objects in the array vs. text string values.  Example:

```
$products = array(
    0 => array('id' => 1, 'product' => 'My Product 1'),
    1 => array('id' => 2, 'product' => 'My Product 2'),
    2 => array('id' => 3, 'product' => 'My Product 3'),
    // and so on up to index of 39...
);
$users = // this is an array of objects and is over 41,000 entries long...  The objects contain only 2 properties.
```

So, my question is, does it matter which array I start with here for speed, reliability, performance, and memory consumption within php?

```
foreach($products as $product)
{
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        // Do Something with the values of $product/$user
    }
}
```

VS.

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        // Do Something with the values of $user/$product
    }
}
```

I'm also open to other ways to do this (possibly with other types of loops) for speed, reliability, performance, and memory reasons.  But 1 thing that is important is that I need the values of each `$product` and `$user`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: Not really, unless you're into micro optimalization. 40 * 41000 is the same as 41000 * 40.

There might be a very tiny difference in the memory footprint depending on which you pick first, since the first array has elements that could be unset after an iteration, but i suspect the difference is very tiny indeed.

Comment: Would it be more productive to unset each key of the first array, after looping through them?  In that case, would need to provide the key in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Like I said, the different would be very minor, unless youre dealing with incredibly large datasets. I've had a dataset of ~41 million records, and thats where i started to notice a difference when I manually started unsetting array elements

Comment: Ok, thanks a ton.  Was a thought I had and was just curious :)

Answer (score 1):

Does it matter which array you start with? No. There might a difference. But i don't think so.

If it is applicable, the better solution myth be to loop for only small array and query database filtered array of users for each product separate. But it depends on you data and on thing you do within the loop.